# Nginx location path not working for custom location

Tags: php, nginx

I have a plan to configure WordPress in a different directory and serve rest of my site from a specific directory.

- /blog/ -> /var/www/wordpress
- /projects/ -> /var/www/projects
- / -> /var/www/

Although when I access `http://{ip-adress}/projects/index.php`, I get 404. Configuration from `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, relevant server directive.

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
            location / {
                    root /var/www;
            }

            location /blog {
                    root /var/www/wordpress;
            }

            location /projects {
                    root /var/www/html/projects;
            }
    }
}
```

[image: Directory structure under www]

Thanks in advance, please feel free to ask for additional details.
PHP v8.1
Nginx 1.14

Comment: The root for project does not match the path shown in your screenshots.

Comment: Are the location directive dependent on the root path? I did comment out the root location directive, reload config and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As your `root` for `/` is already `/var/www` and your `projects` directory is placed inside `/var/www`, there is no need to add a second `location` block for `/projects`.

However, if you would like to add it, you have to adjust the `root` directive in the `projects/` `location` block to match the file system path of your `projects` directory.

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
            location / {
                    root /var/www;
            }

            location /blog {
                    root /var/www/wordpress;
            }

            location /projects {
                    root /var/www/projects; # instead of /var/www/html/projects
            }
    }
}
```